# How to make support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout pane slide towards left

Tags: android, menu, slide

I'm using `support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout`, My app supports two languages, English and Arabic. Android version supported is from 4.2.

For English I'm using default behaviour of `SlidingPaneLayout` ie. menu will be at the left and the content frame opens from left to right. When User selects arabic language. I want everything to be from Right to Left (RTL).

Please tell me any tweek to the `SlidingPaneLayout` such that in 1 shot I can make it RTL ie. menu on the right Side and content frame opens from right to left.

Thanks in advance.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### First add RTL support

In order to support RTL in your app, you first need to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file.

#### Set LTR in SlidingPanLayout

Add in `SlidingPaneLayout`

- `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` for left
- `android:layoutDirection="locale"` determinate by system

Sample: set SlidingPanelLayout in left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/panel_left"
        android:name="onePanelFragment"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/panel_right"
        android:name="twoPanelFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

> remember that the components inside the SliderLayout will also affect their alignment